# SqlConnection with VB.NET, is there System.Data.dll missing?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

With my VBA experience I´m trying VB.NET now. First I need a connection to my MS SQL Server.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim cnn As SqlConnection
        connetionString = "Data Source=MyDS;Initial Catalog=MyIC;User ID=MyUser;Password=MyPW"
        cnn = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            cnn.Open()
            MsgBox("Connection Open ! ")
            cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Can not open connection ! ")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error: Type "SqlConnection" is not defined.
SqlConnection is also red underlined directly in the Dim cnn - line.
Also there is no intellisense suggestion for it.

I came across System.Data.dll several times on google searches. Is it missing in my system? I tried to import it without success.
Then I searched it in
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5
and
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0
It isn´t there.
Is System.Data.dll my problem?

Win10, Visual Studio Version 17.4.1 (64-Bit)

Maybe I´ve installed Visual Studio incomplete? Or is there an other reason for my problem?

Thank you very much for your time and a hot tip :-)

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting? You probably chose a .NET 6 or 7 Project. What happens if you put the Caret inside one of the squiggling references and press `ALT + ENTER`? -- Assume you get two suggestions about the Package to install. You may want to go for the one that starts with `Microsoft.`

Comment: Hi Jimi, if I understand you and google in the same way it´s .NET version 4.8.04084 on my machine (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full). The rest with caret inside ... I don´t understand. Can you describe it in an other way, please?

Comment: I don't know what Google has to do with any of this. It's your Solution / Project, you have to know what .NET version you're targeting. It's the Template you chose when you created the Solution and it's specified in the properties of each Project in the Solution. In .NET Framework, you should have `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: Hey Jimi, VB.NET is an absolut new world for me. For sure I have to know all this things, and as I know myself I will know it very soon. But the first steps are shaky sometimes. Creating a new project there are a lot of templates and I don´t know them all yet. But thanks a lot, I see my mistake now. I choose Windows Forms-App, not Windows Forms-App (.NET Framework). It runs now! Thank you, have a nice evening!

Comment: WELL, since you're there, at the beginning of something and you can still choose, I suggest you opt for the previous solution, targeting .NET 7. If you don't have it, [just install it](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0). You need to also add the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package via NuGet Package Manager. It takes a few seconds of your time. You'll thank me later; or hate me, you choose that, too :) But I guess you won't

Comment: What's on your machine is irrelevant. Look in the project properties and it will tell you what .NET version you're targeting. If you chose a .NET Framework project template in the first place (they all have .NET Framework in the name) then *System.Data.dll* will almost certainly be referenced by default and you simply have to import the `System.Data.DqlClient` namespace. If you chose a .NET Core project template (.NET 5 and later are based on .NET Core) then you will need to install a NuGet package to reference the required DLL.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [What is .NET Framework?](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/dotnet/what-is-dotnet-framework), [.NET and .NET Core release lifecycle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core), [Microsoft .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework)

Comment: Good evening and thank you for your comments, links and suggestions. I had read it all and more... And I´m not sure if I should read even more or less. I find it a little bit tough to differentiate between .NET, .NET Framework, .NET Core, .NET platform, ... Nevertheless I think/hope I get a feel for this big world. And I´m sure, the praxis will show the way and answer many questions. And maybe I will ask you the others ;-) Thanks a lot!